# Replace string with a specified string

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, conditional-statements, hierarchy

I'm trying to create a condition where I could display only one of the 5 order tags below:

1. For Invoice
2. Invoiced
3. Packed
4. In-Transit
5. Delivered

Here is the condition:

- Loop through all the tags.
- For Invoice is replaced if Invoiced is added.
- Invoiced is replaced if Packed is added.
- Packed is replaced if In-Transit is added.
- In-Transit is replaced if Delivered is added.
- If the tag isn't any of the mentioned above, display it.

If '1. For Invoice' is added and if I add the tag '2. Invoiced', only the latter will be displayed. I'm having difficulties on how to solve this because there are still other tags that need to be displayed. Like if I add DenimTAGS, it needs to be displayed. I just need to display only one of the five tags above. It's sort of like a hierarchy kind of thing.

So if I have an array like this:

```
['DenimTags', '1. For Invoice', '2. Invoiced', '3. Packed']
```

It should be displayed as this:

```
['DenimTags', '3. Packed']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const tags = ['DenimTags', '1. For Invoice', '2. Invoiced', '3. Packed'];
const result = [];
let highestStatus = 0;
let highestStatusName;
    
tags.forEach(tag => { 
  if(isNaN(parseInt(tag[0]))) {
      result.push(tag);
  } else if (parseInt(tag[0]) > highestStatus) {
        highestStatusName = tag;
        highestStatus = tag[0];
  }
})  
result.push(highestStatusName);
console.log(result);
```

Whenever the tag is not one of those 5 starting with a number it is pushed into the result array. Then, the tag with the highest number is pushed into the result array as well.
This might not handle any edge cases that you might have.